# update statement in phpMyAdmin doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, syntax-error

My table ends with fields Top, Medium, Low. By mistake they have been entered as n,n,y but should be n,y,n

For some reason the code below does not work. Instead of changing the data in Medium and Low from n,y to y,n it leaves the Low as it is and placed '0' in the Medium

What have I done wrong, please?

```
UPDATE Copy 
SET Medium = 'y' AND Low = 'n'
WHERE Chain = 'HolidayInn' AND Country = 'USA' AND Low ='y'
```

Answer (score 2):

Columns in the `set` clause should be separated with commas (`,`s), not `and`s:

```
UPDATE Copy
SET    Medium = 'y',
       -- Here ----^
       Low = 'n'
WHERE  Chain = 'HolidayInn' AND Country = 'USA' AND Low ='y'
```